# wso2 message broker 3 on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, wso2-message-broker

is it possible to use the wso2 message broker 3 as a mqtt-broker on a raspberry pi (e.g. RPi 1, Modell B+) or is it better to use Mosquitto (less memory requirment)?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Message Broker is not yet tested with raspberry pi. So there's no real answer until you try. So you can go ahead and have a go. But here are the facts.

1. RPi 1, B+ has 512 MB of memory shared with VGA. So assuming MB has about 300MB of memory to work with, yes it will work but with restrictions posed due to the limited memory.
2. WSO2 MB 3.0.0 supports both amqp and mqtt transports, so you can disable amqp transport via [configs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB300/Advanced+Message+Queueing+Protocol) to have some space for MB to breath.
3. You have to protect the server from high load, by [Tuning Flow Control](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB300/Tuning+Flow+Control).
4. Since WSO2 MB is horizontally scalable, you could create a cluster of Raspberry Pi's to handle the load if you're expecting a considerable amount of traffic.